# FB:SHARE Plugin (on FB Tab) Not Showing Up In IE Only

Tags: internet-explorer, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-iframe, facebook-social-plugins

I'm using the FB Share plugin on a facebook tab, so this is just inside the body tag:

```
<div id="sharebtn">
<fb:share-button href="path-to-redirect-url.html">      </fb:share-button>
</div>
```

The redirect is a go-between page with the meta information I want the pop-up to be filled with, and it forwards the user to the full address of the tab the user is sharing.

basic fb.init:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script> 
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : '12345668blahblah',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
     channelUrl : 'channelurlblahblah.php', // 
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
  });
```

So the thing is, it works properly (display) in all browsers when you view the tab contents in isolation, ie:

```
http://www.atdesigner.com/c/byf/fb/recipes/
```

And it works if you view the tab (via iframe) in facebook, in all browsers except, you guessed it, IE.

```
https://www.facebook.com/BackyardFarms?sk=app_222628611095624
```

Why isn't the share button showing up in IE, when viewed through the FB iframe?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think some versions of IE require  `<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. (somebody rep this guy, I'm too much a noob to be givn rep-a-bility!) :)

Comment: Hmm, that's a thought. If you don't want the mention of FBML in your code, it looks like the current recommendation is `<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">`.

Comment: Yes - this is what I've done (thanks!) 

for future readers: the next threat of deprecation comes from fb-share itself (FB pushing users to use the Like plugin instead).